# Kotlin Coroutine GlobalScope documentation clarity

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, global-scope

I'm having a hard time understanding the usages and documentation for GlobalScope.
The docs states:

> A global CoroutineScope not bound to any job.
>
> Global scope is used to launch top-level coroutines which are
> operating on the whole application lifetime and are not cancelled
> prematurely. Another use of the global scope is operators running in
> Dispatchers.Unconfined, which don’t have any job associated with them.
>
> Application code usually should use an application-defined
> CoroutineScope. Using async or launch on the instance of GlobalScope
> is highly discouraged.

1. What does it mean when GlobalScope is not bound to any job? Because I can do

   ```
   val job = GlobalScope.launch {
       // some work
   }
   job.cancel()
   ```
2. It says they are not canceled prematurely. What does this mean? As you can see above I can cancel it.
3. Lastly it says, it operates on the whole application lifetime. So the scope stays alive until the application dies. How does this compare with `CoroutineScope`? When I exit an Android `Activity` in the middle of a running `CoroutineScope`, it'll still be alive and runs until completion. Does it just mean the `CoroutineScope` will get cleaned up w/ garbage collection after it completes and `GlobalScope` wont?

link to docs:
https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. What does it mean when GlobalScope is not bound to any job? Because I can do...

This refers to the lack of `Job` object associated to the `CoroutineScope`, not individual coroutine `Job`s within the "Scope".

> 2. It says they are not canceled prematurely. What does this mean? As you can see above I can cancel it.

Calling `GlobalScope.cancel()` at any point will throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.

so this would produce the same error :

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val myScope : CoroutineScope = object : CoroutineScope {
        override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.IO // no job added i.e + SupervisorJob()
    }


    val job = myScope.launch { longRunningTask() }

    Thread.sleep(5_000)
    job.cancel() // this is fine - individual coroutine cancelled
    myScope.cancel() // this will throw an error, same as GlobalScope.cancel()
    
}
```

> 3. Lastly it says, it operates on the whole application lifetime. So the scope stays alive until the application dies. How does this compare with CoroutineScope? When I exit an Android Activity in the middle of a running CoroutineScope, it'll still be alive and runs until completion. Does it just mean the CoroutineScope will get cleaned up w/ garbage collection after it completes and GlobalScope wont?

`GlobalScope` is an object class - a singleton, thus lasts as long as the process it runs in.  `GlobalScope` implements `CoroutineScope` its just a predefined scope that comes with the library.  Coroutines can be launched from `GlobalScope` but the caller must take care to retain the `Job` object and cancel each coroutine via the `Job`.  When using custom `CoroutineScope` you can have greater control on what happens when you call the extension function `CoroutineScope.cancel()` - for instance cancelling all child coroutines "running" in that scope.

I'm no authority on the subject but that's how I interpet the documentation and observed behaviours of the library.

If I'm honest I think most people struggle to explain coroutines simply and concisely - most articles on the subject are not easy reading and usually I come away more confused.  Having delved into the library source code a bit after it usually demistifies things somewhat, but you can also see it is still very much in a state of continuing development.